# How to get the first and last dates in a range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have table A in SSMS as such:

| EMPLOYEE | TEACHING | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | SCIENCE | 1/1/2001 | 5/10/2001 |
| 123 | SCIENCE | 8/20/2001 | 12/16/2001 |
| 123 | SCIENCE | 1/18/2002 | 5/8/2002 |
| 123 | HISTORY | 8/15/2002 | 12/10/2002 |
| 123 | SCIENCE | 1/3/2003 | 5/6/2003 |
| 123 | SCIENCE | 8/1/2003 | 12/3/2003 |

I would like for my output to be the following

| EMPLOYEE | TEACHING | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | SCIENCE | 1/1/2001 | 5/8/2002 |
| 123 | SCIENCE | 1/3/2003 | 12/3/2003 |
| 123 | HISTORY | 8/15/2002 | 12/10/2002 |

Essentially I'd like to get the first START_DATE and last END_DATE for EMPLOYEE and TEACHING within each block. A way I tried to work around this was by creating two ranks, one ASC and one DESC but it would give me 1/1/2001 - 12/3/2003 for science which is not what I want.

History is breaking the chain as someone already commented.

Comment: Your example data doesn't match your description. Your expected results have different start and end dates for the same employee with the same teaching values.

Comment: Why are you expecting two rows Science?

Comment: @Stu I'm guessing that the History record breaks the chain, so they want to get the next block of Science records as it's own set with it's min/max. But the description doesn't make that clear.

Comment: Yes, the history record breaks the chain, let me clarify that in my description.

Comment: Yes should have noticed that only reading with one-eye on the (pretty crappy) phone app; searching for a gaps-islands solution will likely help.

Comment: Your table isn't in SSMS - SSMS is purely a client UI to SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest following solution:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
  EMPLOYEE int,
  TEACHING varchar(MAX),
  START_DATE datetime2,
  END_DATE datetime2
)

INSERT @T VALUES
(123, 'SCIENCE', '1/1/2001', '5/10/2001'),
(123, 'SCIENCE', '8/20/2001', '12/16/2001'),
(123, 'SCIENCE', '1/18/2002', '5/8/2002'),
(123, 'HISTORY', '8/15/2002', '12/10/2002'),
(123, 'SCIENCE', '1/3/2003', '5/6/2003'),
(123, 'SCIENCE', '8/1/2003', '12/3/2003'),
(124, 'SCIENCE', '1/1/2001', '5/10/2001'),
(124, 'SCIENCE', '8/20/2001', '12/16/2001'),
(124, 'SCIENCE', '1/18/2002', '5/8/2002'),
(124, 'HISTORY', '8/15/2002', '12/10/2002'),
(124, 'SCIENCE', '1/3/2003', '5/6/2003'),
(124, 'SCIENCE', '8/1/2003', '12/3/2003');

WITH Discriminated AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY START_DATE)-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE, TEACHING ORDER BY START_DATE) Discriminator
  FROM @T
)
SELECT EMPLOYEE, TEACHING, MIN(START_DATE) START_DATE, MAX(END_DATE) END_DATE
FROM Discriminated
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE, TEACHING, Discriminator
ORDER BY EMPLOYEE, START_DATE
```

I also assume you would like to calculate each EMPLOYEE separately. The trick is to mark consecutive groups (see query in CTE).

Comment: That did it!! Now let me go back and absorb this logic